# Can you attach an event to a property that you can't modify?

Tags: c#, events

I'm trying to have some code run whenever a property on an object is changed, but I don't have direct access to that object as it is from a referenced class.

For example, let's call the class Application and it has a property on it called ActiveObject of type object.

I want to be able to know whenever **Application.ActiveObject** is changed.

I'm thinking I should be able to attach an event to it, but all the examples I've found of events are only for properties that I would create myself, not something that is from a referenced class.

Comment: what about IObservable<ActiveObject> ?

Comment: If your code is the only code that changes Application.ActiveObject property, you can wrap the Application class into another class to raise an event when ActiveObject property is changed.

Comment: I'll look into using IObservable on the object. In regard to Mehrzad's response, my code doesn't change the property. The property changing is due to operations that are going on in the referenced class. I just need to figure out a way to be notified whenever that property is changed.